# Axios Get request sometimes doesn't go through

Tags: reactjs

recently i have been working on my react project. my code is working fine most of the time.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import { Navigate, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import API from "../backend";
import { isAutheticated } from "../auth";

import ReactPaginate from "react-paginate";

import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";

import Spinner from "react-bootstrap/Spinner";

const Body = () => {
  // set values (got from api)
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    bookingId: "",
    email: "",
    status: "",
    error: "",
    success: "",
  });
  // set api response as array, so that i can loop through using map
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  // if some click submit
  const [didsubmit, setDidSumbit] = useState(false);

  // set and get default booking status
  const [myValue, setMyValue] = useState("");

  // if something changes
  const [didChange, setDidChange] = useState(false);

  // for pagination
  const [pageChange, setPageChange] = useState(false);

  // total pages in pagination
  const [allTotalPages, setAllTotalPages] = useState("");

  // default page number (used in api get response)
  const [num, setNum] = useState(1);

  // used for searching
  const [details, setDetails] = useState({
    email: false,
  });
  // search state
  const [search, setSearch] = useState(false);

  // if site is loading
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  // destructuring token from localstorage
  const { token } = isAutheticated();

  // dataObject for api call
  const tokenKey = {
    headers: {
      authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  };

  // api call
  const axiosGetCall = async () => {
    try {
      let res;

      if (search === true) {
        res = await Axios.get(
          `${API}/allorders?page=${num}&useremail=${details.email}`,
          tokenKey
        );
        setSearch(false);
      } else {
        res = await Axios.get(`${API}/allorders?page=${num}`, tokenKey);
      }

      setValues({ ...values, success: "", error: "" });
      const data = await res.data.bookings;
      const totalItems = await res.data.Total;

      setData(data);

      const totalPages = Math.ceil(totalItems / 5);

      setAllTotalPages(totalPages);

      setPageChange(false);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      setSearch(false);
      setLoading(false);
      setValues({ ...values, success: "", error: "" });
    }
  };

  //GET API NORMAL FOR FIRST LOAD
  useEffect(() => {
    axiosGetCall();
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  //GET API IF DID CHANGE
  useEffect(() => {
    if (didChange === true) {
      // if there is something in details do this
      if (details.email === false) {
        axiosGetCall();
      } else {
        setSearch(true);
        axiosGetCall();
      }
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [didChange]);

  //GET API IF DID Search
  useEffect(() => {
    if (search === true) {
      axiosGetCall();
    }

    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [search]);

  //GET API WHEN PAGE CHANGES
  useEffect(() => {
    if (pageChange === true) {
      setValues({ ...values, success: "", error: "" });
      // if there is something in details do this
      if (details.email === false) {
        axiosGetCall();
      } else {
        setSearch(true);
        axiosGetCall();
      }
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [pageChange]);

  const onSubmit = (event, id, mail, val) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setValues({
      ...values,
      bookingId: id,
      email: mail,
      status: val,
      success: "",
      error: "",
    });
    setMyValue(val);
    setDidSumbit(true);
  };

  const newStatus = {
    status: myValue,
    id: values.bookingId,
  };

  // POST API
  useEffect(() => {
    const axiosUpdateCall = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await Axios.post(`${API}/changeorder`, newStatus, tokenKey);

        setDidSumbit(false);
        setDidChange(false);
        setValues({ ...values, success: "Changed Successfully", error: "" });
      } catch (error) {
        setValues({
          ...values,
          error: error.response.data.error[0],
          success: "",
        });
        setDidChange(false);
      }
    };
    if (didChange) {
      axiosUpdateCall();
    }
  }, [didChange]);

  // Error Toast
  const errorToast = () => {
    toast.error(`${values.error}`, {
      position: "top-right",
      autoClose: 8000,
      hideProgressBar: false,
      closeOnClick: true,
      pauseOnHover: true,
      draggable: true,
      progress: undefined,
      theme: "dark",
    });
  };

  // Sucess Toast
  const successToast = () => {
    toast.success(`${values.success}`, {
      position: "top-right",
      autoClose: true,
      hideProgressBar: false,
      closeOnClick: true,
      pauseOnHover: true,
      draggable: true,
      progress: undefined,
      theme: "dark",
    });
  };

  // pagination stuff
  const handlePageClick = async (data) => {
    let currentPagex = data.selected + 1;
    setNum(currentPagex);
    setPageChange(true);
    setLoading(true);
    setValues({ ...values, success: "", error: "" });
  };

  // search stuff
  const onSearch = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setSearch(true);
    setLoading(true);
    setValues({ ...values, success: "", error: "" });
  };

  // handling changes on pages
  const onHandleChange = (val) => (event) => {
    setDetails({ ...details, [val]: event.target.value });
    setValues({ ...values, success: "", error: "" });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ToastContainer
        position="top-right"
        autoClose={5000}
        hideProgressBar={false}
        newestOnTop={false}
        closeOnClick={false}
        rtl={false}
        pauseOnFocusLoss
        draggable
        pauseOnHover
        theme="dark"
      />

      {values.error && errorToast()}

      {values.success && successToast()}

      <div style={{ display: didsubmit ? "none" : "block" }}>
        <section className="section dashboard">
          <div className="row justify-content-md-center">
            <div className="col-lg-6">
              <div className="input-group">
                <input
                  type="search"
                  className="form-control rounded"
                  placeholder="example@gmail.com"
                  aria-label="Search"
                  aria-describedby="search-addon"
                  onChange={onHandleChange("email")}
                />
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="btn btn-outline-primary"
                  onClick={onSearch}
                  disabled={search}
                >
                  {search === true ? "Loading.." : "Search"}
                </button>
                &nbsp; &nbsp;
                <a href="/main" className="btn btn-outline-primary">
                  Reload
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>

      <main id="main" className="main">
        <section className="section dashboard ">
          <div className="row justify-content-md-center">
            <div className={didsubmit ? "col-lg-6" : "col-lg-12"}>
              <div className="row">
                {/*  */}
                <div className="col-12">
                  <div className="card recent-sales overflow-auto">
                    <div className="card-body">
                      <h3 className="card-title">
                        {didsubmit === true
                          ? "Change Booking Status"
                          : "Recent Bookings "}
                        <span></span>
                      </h3>

                      {loading === true ? (
                        <>
                          {" "}
                          <Spinner animation="border" role="status">
                            <span className="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
                          </Spinner>
                        </>
                      ) : (
                        <>
                          <table className="table table-borderless datatable">
                            {didsubmit === true ? (
                              <></>
                            ) : (
                              <thead>
                                <tr>
                                  <th scope="col">Name</th>
                                  <th scope="col">User Email</th>
                                  <th scope="col">Customer Phone</th>
                                  <th scope="col">Payment Recept</th>
                                  <th scope="col">Order id</th>
                                  <th scope="col">Package Name</th>
                                  <th scope="col">Total Kids</th>
                                  <th scope="col">Total Adults</th>
                                  <th scope="col">Total Price</th>
                                  <th scope="col">BookedFor</th>
                                  <th scope="col">created On</th>
                                  <th scope="col">Status</th>
                                </tr>
                              </thead>
                            )}
                            {/*  */}
                            <tbody>
                              {didsubmit === true ? (
                                <>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td>
                                      {" "}
                                      <p>Email: {values.email}</p>
                                      <p>Current Status: {values.status}</p>
                                      <div className="col-3">
                                        <select
                                          onChange={(e) =>
                                            setMyValue(e.target.value)
                                          }
                                          defaultValue={values.status}
                                        >
                                          <option>Pending</option>
                                          <option>Unpaid</option>
                                          <option>Bank</option>
                                          <option>Bank-Paid</option>
                                          <option>Success</option>
                                        </select>
                                      </div>
                                      &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                      <div className="float-end">
                                        <button
                                          className="btnx btn-primary"
                                          disabled={didChange}
                                          onClick={() => {
                                            setDidSumbit(false);
                                          }}
                                        >
                                          Back
                                        </button>
                                        &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                        <button
                                          className="btnx btn-primary"
                                          disabled={didChange}
                                          onClick={() => {
                                            setDidChange(true);
                                          }}
                                        >
                                          {didChange
                                            ? "Loading.."
                                            : "Change Status"}
                                        </button>
                                      </div>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                </>
                              ) : (
                                <>
                                  {data.map((e, i) => (
                                    <tr key={e._id}>
                                      <td scope="row">
                                        {e.tourDetails[0].username}
                                      </td>
                                      <td scope="row">
                                        <p>{e.tourDetails[0].email}</p>
                                      </td>
                                      <td scope="row">
                                        <p>{e.tourDetails[0].userphone}</p>
                                      </td>
                                      <td scope="row">
                                        <p>{e.paymentid}</p>
                                      </td>
                                      <td scope="row">
                                        <p>{e.orderId}</p>
                                      </td>
                                      <td>{e.tourDetails[0].name}</td>
                                      <td>{e.Childquantity}</td>
                                      <td>{e.Adultquantity}</td>
                                      <td>₹{e.overAllTotal}</td>
                                      <td>
                                        <span className="text-primary">
                                          {e.bookedFor}
                                        </span>
                                      </td>
                                      <td>{e.createdAt.slice(0, 10)}</td>
                                      <td>
                                        {e.orderStatus === "Success" && (
                                          <span className="badge bg-success">
                                            {e.orderStatus}
                                          </span>
                                        )}

                                        {e.orderStatus === "Bank" && (
                                          <span className="badge bg-dark">
                                            {e.orderStatus}
                                          </span>
                                        )}

                                        {e.orderStatus === "Bank-Paid" && (
                                          <span className="badge bg-secondary">
                                            {e.orderStatus}
                                          </span>
                                        )}

                                        {e.orderStatus === "Unpaid" && (
                                          <span className="badge bg-danger">
                                            {e.orderStatus}
                                          </span>
                                        )}

                                        {e.orderStatus === "Pending" && (
                                          <span className="badge bg-warning">
                                            {e.orderStatus}
                                          </span>
                                        )}
                                      </td>
                                      <td>
                                        <button
                                          className="btnx btn-primary"
                                          disabled={didsubmit}
                                          onClick={(event) => {
                                            onSubmit(
                                              event,
                                              e._id,
                                              e.tourDetails[0].email,
                                              e.orderStatus
                                            );
                                          }}
                                        >
                                          {didsubmit
                                            ? "loading.."
                                            : "Change Status"}
                                        </button>
                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                  ))}
                                </>
                              )}
                            </tbody>

                            {/*  */}
                          </table>
                        </>
                      )}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            {/*  */}
          </div>
        </section>
      </main>
      {/*  */}
      <div style={{ display: didsubmit ? "none" : "block" }}>
        <ReactPaginate
          previousLabel={"previous"}
          nextLabel={"next"}
          breakLabel={"..."}
          pageCount={allTotalPages}
          marginPagesDisplayed={2}
          pageRangeDisplayed={3}
          onPageChange={handlePageClick}
          containerClassName={"pagination justify-content-center"}
          pageClassName={"page-item"}
          pageLinkClassName={"page-link"}
          previousClassName={"page-item"}
          previousLinkClassName={"page-link"}
          nextClassName={"page-item"}
          nextLinkClassName={"page-link"}
          breakClassName={"page-item"}
          breakLinkClassName={"page-link"}
          activeClassName={"active"}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Body;
```

this is the whole code, here most of the time my get response works fine. sometimes it doesn't hit the route.

[image]

sometimes Get request doesn't hit after post request

> POST "http://127.0.0.1:4000/api/changeorder".

> GET "http://127.0.0.1:4000/api/allorders?page=1".

[image]
I guess my Get request is loading before post request so the virtual dom isn't updating.

Comment: do a dry run of your logic, may be there could be a problem with logic

Comment: but if it was issue with the logic then it shouldnt be working right ?

Comment: i think my get request is loading before post request is completed..

Comment: Can you explain full workflow to make it happen ?